# Quarkus Keystore Password File

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, microprofile, quarkus-native, eclipse-microprofile-config

I have my keystore password saved on the server, which I am pulling from a vault. I want to provide a path to quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password instead of a hardcoded password. Do we have any interceptors before the start so that password can be loaded from that file using some @override implementation?

Or some other approach to this. I don't want to put the password file in the project. I want to provide the path in the application.yaml.

Quarkus 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vault extension https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.vault/quarkus-vault/

Or if you want, you can setup the yaml file to access the keystore password file from an environment variable

yaml:

```
quarkus:
  http:
    ssl:
      certificate:
        key-store-password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ENV_VAR}
```

Before starting the application, export the environment variable like this:

```
export KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ENV_VAR=$(cat /path/to/keystore/password/file)
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hesitant to export some password as env variable. I provided a configSourceFactory as mentioned official doc.